# IIS 7.5 ARR/URL ReWrite2 ReversProxy to Apache on Virtual Machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, arr

Here's the scenario.

Server is Win2k8, running IIS 7.5.   I have ARR and URL Rewrite2 installed.

I have a virtual box running the latest Ubuntu Server.  Apache, mySQL, PHP are all installed.

I have IIS configured as a reverse proxy, and have setup a URL ReWrite as such:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.1.17/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have verified that http://dev.o7t.in correctly gets routed to the configured site in apache on the VM, however, http://wp.o7t.in gets directed to the same exact place.  Here's the config from both sites in apache:

Dev:

```
# NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName devo7tin
    ServerAlias dev.o7t.in
    ServerAdmin support@o7t.in
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/dev/>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

wp:

```
# NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName wpo7tin
    ServerAlias wp.o7t.in
    ServerAdmin support@o7t.in
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and NameVirtualHost is configured already in ports.conf

What I am noticing is the Host Header, always reverts to the IP address of the virtual machine (in this case 192.168.1.17), and completely ignores the requested host.

So....   how can I get around this, and pass my VM the correct HTTP_HOST header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was right.  It was an IIS thing not sending the HTTP_HOST header.   Of course, why would they post it anywhere, but apparently ARR by default disables, however, it can be enabled via:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/proxy /preserveHostHeader:"True" /commit:apphost
```

Configured this, and it now works!

Comment: Thanks.  Appcmd is located in "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\"